# Use numeric value of `colnames` to recalculate columns in a data.frame using `dplyr`'s `mutate_at` or an alternative

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `df` where I want to recalculate some columns based on the value of that columns `colnames`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(year = 1:3, "10" = 0:2, "20" = 3:5)
colnames(df)[2:3] <- c("10", "20")
df
  year 10 20
1    1  0  3
2    2  1  4
3    3  2  5
```

The expected output is `col_name - col_values`. I can generate the expected output with:

```
df %>% mutate(`10` = 10 - `10`) %>% mutate(`20` = 20 - `20`)
  year 10 20
1    1 10 17
2    2  9 16
3    3  8 15
```

How can I generate the same output without explicitly copying the respecting `colnames` value?

I tried the following code (which works):

```
df %>% mutate(`10` = as.numeric(colnames(.)[2]) - `10`) %>% mutate(`20` = as.numeric(colnames(.)[3]) - `20`)
```

So I tried to further reduce this but could only think of:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(-year), ~ as.numeric(colnames(.)[.]))
```

which can obviously not work since the `.` has two meanings..

**How can I achieve my expected output using `mutate_at` or an alternative?**

Comment: Don't know the full story, but if we could keep numbers as values in rows not as column names, i.e.: long instead of wide format, then this question would be obsolete.

Comment: @zx8754: I think you're right. Probably I should change my format to long.. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reshape, do stuff, then reshape again:

```
gather(df, key = "k", value = "v", -year) %>% 
  mutate(v = as.numeric(k) - v) %>% 
  spread(key = "k", value = "v")

#   year 10 20
# 1    1 10 17
# 2    2  9 16
# 3    3  8 15
```

Comment: Nice approach! This however does change column and row ordering in my real example. Is there a possibility to keep the ordering of the original `df`?

Comment: you would need to add a row ID to your data, such as `df$row_id = seq_len(nrow(df))`, and then you can reorder on the row ID. (not, you'll need to exclude `row_id` from `gather` with `-row_id`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `mutate_at`

```
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    mutate_at(2:3, list(~ as.numeric(as_name(quo(.)))- .))
#  year 10 20
#1    1 10 17
#2    2  9 16
#3    3  8 15
```

Or this can be also done with `deparse(substitute`

```
df %>% 
     mutate_at(2:3, list(~ as.numeric(deparse(substitute(.))) - .))
```

---

Or using an option with `map`

```
map_dfc(names(df)[2:3], ~
          df %>%
              select(.x) %>% 
              mutate(!! .x :=   as.numeric(.x) - !! sym(.x))) %>% 
     bind_cols(df %>% 
                  select(year), .)
```

---

Or with `imap`

```
df[-1] <- imap(df[-1], ~ as.numeric(.y) - .x)
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R, we can use `lapply`

```
df[-1] <- lapply(names(df[-1]), function(x) as.numeric(x) - df[,x])

#  year 10 20
#1    1 10 17
#2    2  9 16
#3    3  8 15
```

Or `mapply`

```
df[-1] <- mapply(`-`, as.numeric(names(df[-1])), df[-1])
```